# Unable to write the base64 encoded string to the file

Tags: html, angular, fileapi

Hi I am facing a big issue while sending data from Angular 4

i have the following base64 encoded string

**data:text/plain;base64,SEkNCndlbGNvbWUgdG8gQW5ndWxhciEh**

while writing it to the file getting the following output

u뚵쭾隊vڱI
welcome to Angular!!

but it should display the following content on file while writing

HI 
welcome to angular!!

i got the above encoded string by running the following code

```
 let reader = new FileReader();
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.get('fileData').setValue({
          filename: file.name,
          filetype: file.type,
          value: reader.result,//.split(',')[1]
          // data: reader.readAsText(reader.result)
        });
```

Comment: For some reason your base64 string seems messed up. If I decode it will have an enter after hi. SGkgd2VsY29tZSB0byBBbmd1bGFyISE= This base64 encoded string should work.

Comment: how to resolve it...

Comment: I am facing same issue , If any one give an answer that will help us